# the npx create-react-app command is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarn-v2

i wanna test reactjs but the npx cmd is not working knowing that i worcked with react befor but it was with yarn .

here is the result `npx create-react-app wa`

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.yarnpkg.com/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your-proxy-server
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hamada Salim G Trd\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-07T07_07_12_866Z-debug-0.log
```